# iPhone app crashes when passing data in prepareForSegue:sender

Tags: ios, iphone, segue

I've been trying to pass data from one tableViewController to another, but as soon as I assign a value to a property in my second tableViewController the app crashes, giving me the message "...unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x715c340...".
Here is the code I have used:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"displayWordlist"]){
        DisplayWordlist *dwl = (DisplayWordlist *)[segue destinationViewController];
        dwl.apa = @"hej";
    }
}
```

As soon as the program reaches 'dwl.apa = @"hej";' it crashes. I have both made a property of apa and synthesized it.

Comment: what is a `apa` ? is it a `NSString`?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: dwl is nil, I guess? What does your debugger say? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set the class of this view controller to DisplayWordlist *in the Storyboard*. If you don't, dwl will be assumed to be an instance of UIViewController despite the cast.

Comment: But what if he did ? Although correct this should have been asked in a comment unless you are 100% sure this is the problem.

Comment: @DrewC That solved it, I cannot believe I forgot that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2157416 One would think that casting the segue's destinationViewController would be enough. I've made this mistake myself.